# Как вывести в слайдер разные картинки

Tags: jquery

На странице сделаны два слайдера http://strdv.inetech.ru/. В оба слайдера выводятся пункты из одного и того же каталога. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы второй слайдер начинал прокручиваться с другого пункта, брал пункты начиная с другого номера или в рандомном порядке, ну то есть, чтобы в слайдерах крутились разные картинки?

Answer (score 1):

Можно:

```
 jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        start: 3
    });
```

На сайте карусели есть [документация](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)  с примерами.

Ну и в следующий раз указывай, что за слайдер используешь.

Comment: да, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Первый слайдер -->
    jQuery('#mycarousel_1').jcarousel({
        start: 1,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: "circular",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4,
        animation: 5000,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
<!-- Второй слайдер -->
    jQuery('#mycarousel_2').jcarousel({
        start: 4,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: "circular",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4,
        animation: 5000,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
```

Comment: да, спасибо)